# EDNS Client IP support - on a Linux VM with BIND ( acting as forwarder )

Tags: dns

I have a Linux VM with bind installed which is acting as a DNS forwarder to forward the requests to my DNS server.

```
acl goodclients {
10.0.0.0/16;
localhost;
localnets;
};

options {
  directory "/var/cache/bind";

  recursion yes;

  allow-recursion { any; };
  allow-query { any; };
  allow-query-cache { any; };

  forwarders {
     10.1.0.4;
  };
  forward only;

  dnssec-enable no;
  dnssec-validation no;

  auth-nxdomain no;   
  listen-on { any; };
};
```

This forwarder VM is not sending the EDNS IP to my DNS server.

What additional config is required for it to support ECS?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! This site is meant for programming questions, system administration questions like yours are more likely to get a useful answer at https://serverfault.com.

Comment: Improved code formatting, removed request for "generic" help.

Comment: Which bind version? You need at least `9.10.5 S` see https://kb.isc.org/article/AA-01310/109/BIND9-Significant-Features-Matrix.html . Then search for `ecs` keyword in documentation: https://www.isc.org/bind-9-11-arm/